# Pythonic way to check if two lists are equal in size

Tags: python, performance, list

Whats the most pythonic or efficent way to check if two lists are equal in size?

The only thing I can think of is

```
len(list_a) == len(list_b)
```

but that seems like it would take a lot more processing power than necessary, especially if the check needs to be done frequently and on large lists.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why would this require a lot of processing power?

Comment: Oh, I'm under the impression that `len` counts the list each time it's called, so each time this condition is called, it'd count two lists that might be millions of elements in length. I very well could be wrong and the list itself could store the count and `len` just returns that count

Comment: Profile the code first

Comment: @KeiNagase: no, a list stores the number of elements explicitly, so it is an *O(1)* operation.

Comment: No, this works in constant time, and is as fast as you could get.